# Make Changes to AOSP and Flash it on the mobile device

Tags: android, android-source

I want to make changes to AOSP multi-window feature.

I would like to know how do we make those Changes?

Also, I would like to know after making changes to AOSP how do I flash the modified AOSP on my device.

Answer (score -1):

Flashing AOSP based ROM will require device vendors. Then you need configure Your device and create custom make files. All about adding new device is [here](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device). I think You should follow [these](https://source.android.com/setup/) instructions, apply Your changes, run system on emulator and then try to extract Your vendors.